# Show jQuery like alert or RadWindow alert in DNN 7.x

Tags: jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, alert, radwindow

I am using the latest DNN 7.02. **Is there any way to convert an regular javascript alert to either a jQuery UI alert or a RadWindow alert?**  The alert I am using right now is as in code below. I would like to make the message appear in bold and large size font. I know all this is possible in jQuery UI and also in radAlert.

I cannot change any code except for adding html, javascript to existing DNN pages.

```
alert('Content has been copied');
```

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to use dnnAlert ( which is a jQuery UI plugin for dnnAlert that is included in regular DNN install) in place of regular alert, *but the problem was that when I click on OK button, the page automatically scrolled to the top, which is very annoying*.

```
            $.dnnAlert({
            text: 'Copied code to clipboard',
            dialogClass: 'dnnFormPopup',
            title: 'Copy Successful',
            modal:false
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter `alert()`:

```
(function() {
    window.alert = function() {
        // do whatever you want with arguments[0]
    };
})();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B3PvU/)

Comment: Is this cross-browser and blocking like the regular alert?